# column_property (or other extra column) with window function?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sqlalchemy, where-clause

I have the following situation, using SQLAlchemy with a MySQL database. Assume a Person table that looks like this:

```
+------+-----------+----------+------------+
|  ID  | firstname | lastname | startdate  |
+------+-----------+----------+------------+
|   43 | Bob       | Smith    | 2016-12-04 |
|  873 | Mary      | Jones    | 2018-05-01 |
|  120 | Bob       | Smith    | 2020-04-02 |
|  339 | Bob       | Jones    | 2019-03-01 |
| 1022 | Bob       | Smith    | 2015-11-21 |
+------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I need to generate an extra column (or any equivalent solution) having the property: For anyone having the same firstname and lastname, return a sequence number ordered by the startdate. If a person doesn't share a firstname and lastname, return NULL. The desired output is:

```
+------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|  ID  | firstname | lastname | startdate  | identifier |
+------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|   43 | Bob       | Smith    | 2016-12-04 | 2          |
|  873 | Mary      | Jones    | 2018-05-01 | NULL       |
|  120 | Bob       | Smith    | 2020-04-02 | 3          |
|  339 | Bob       | Jones    | 2019-03-01 | NULL       |
| 1022 | Bob       | Smith    | 2015-11-21 | 1          |
+------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I'd like to do this for any way of looking at the data; that is, whether I'm doing a search on all people, or just a single record, I can still see that ID 120 is #3 of all the "Bob Smith"s.

I assume that the solution involves using a window function, but I can't figure out how to use this in a `column_property`, or whether `column_property` is in fact the right way to add this to my table. This `identifier` would only be used for display purposes; I'd never be sorting or querying on it, so I could indeed only generate it when needed. However, it should still be part of the Person object, so that however I get there, `person.identifier` will be populated. And ideally this wouldn't be problematically slow, so that if I do `SELECT * FROM person`, I'm not firing off a zillion individual queries.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#window-functions

Answer (score 4):

You can use window functions. In pure SQL:

```
select t.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by firstname, lastname) > 1
        then row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by startdate) 
    end as identifier
from mytable t
```

Disclaimer: I cannot tell how to express this in SQL Alchemy.

---

If you need a `WHERE` clause, then use a subquery (otherwise, the `WHERE` clause applies to the window function as well):

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        case when count(*) over(partition by firstname, lastname) > 1
            then row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by startdate) 
        end as identifier
    from mytable t
) t
where id = 120
```

Comment: Wow. OK, that does work. The catch is, it only works for  the situation when I'm looking at the full table; if I add `WHERE id=120`, I of course get NULL for poor Bob Smith #3. How could I deal with that? Bob Smith #3 has to be Bob Smith #3, if I'm looking at just him, or everyone who started in 2020, or everyone who started in April of any year. (And, of course, converting this to SQLAlchemy will still be tough.)

Comment: @user9219182: if you need a `WHERE` clause, then use a subquery. See my edit.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you! Now to figure out how to convert this....