# Convert a query to a column_property?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

[Yesterday I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64845608/column-property-or-other-extra-column-with-window-function) about a complex (to me) MySQL query that I needed to use as a `column_property`. A kind user (who doesn't do SQLAlchemy so I won't bother to link him) answered the SQL part of it:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        case when count(*) over(partition by firstname, lastname) > 1
            then row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by startdate) 
        end as identifier
    from person t
) t
where id = ?
```

After far too long a struggle, I was able to convert this to a function in SQLA:

```
def get_identifier(id):

    mycase = db.case([
        (
            db.func.count().over(partition_by=[Person.firstname, Person.lastname]) > 1,
            db.func.row_number().over(partition_by=[Person.firstname, Person.lastname], order_by=Person.startdate)
        )
    ]).label('identifier')

    subq = db.session.query(Person.id, mycase).subquery('subq')

    identifier = db.session.query(subq.c.identifier).\
        filter(subq.c.id == id).scalar()
    return identifier
```

However, I am stuck on how to make this work as a `column_property`, and there aren't that many examples of that I can find. Even the simple part--if I'm in the `Person` class, then I don't have access to `Person.firstname` etc.--is confusing. And a further complication is that the actual query (the above was simplified) uses a complex order_by clause that is itself generated from another column_property in Person; that clause actually looks like `order_by=[*Person.person_order]`.

If column_property isn't right, is there some other way to attach this function as an extra column, or anything equivalent (e.g. a method that can be called) in a Person object?